# Limit input to alphabet only [a-z, A-Z,SPACE,PERIOD]

Tags: c++

I'm trying to limit user input to certain characters only [a-z,A-Z,SPACE,PERIOD], I can't get this function right?!

```
void setName()
{

    char fname[20];
    unsigned int ascii_val;
    while(ascii_val<65 || ascii_val>90)
    {
        cout << "First Name: ";
        cin.ignore().getline(fname,20);

        for(int i=0; i<sizeof(fname); i++)
        {
            ascii_val = toupper(fname[i]);
            if(ascii_val==32 || ascii_val==46 || ascii_val==0) //Exception to allow SPACE and PERIOD
            {
                ascii_val=65;
            };
            if(ascii_val<65 || ascii_val>90)
            {
                cout << "Only Alphabet [a-z,A-Z,SPACE,DOT] Allowed!\n";
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    newfname = fname;
}
```

Comment: Before you go any further, first replace things like `65` and `90` with `'A'` and `'Z'`.

Comment: A note about `ignore` Don't throw them in just in case you might need to ignore something. If you really do need an `ignore`, place it after the IO transaction that left unwanted characters in the stream. If you place `ignore` before some other transaction then sooner or later you will reach that transaction without any garbage in the stream and get to experience "Dude, where's my `char`?" first hand.

Comment: If you think no one's name, first or otherwise, is longer than 20 characters, you're going to have a bad time. Use `std::string` instead of raw `char` arrays.

Comment: [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) may be useful to you.

Comment: Warning: in `for(int i=0; i<sizeof(fname); i++)` what if the name doesn't fill up the whole array?

Comment: Why `while(ascii_val<65 || ascii_val>90)`?  And note that `ascii_val` is uninitialised at that point, first time through.

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @Biffen interesting, but students have to do what they've been assigned ;)

Comment: "_I can't get this function right?!_" <- not a problem description. What happens when you build/run the code? Why is that wrong or insufficient? Show sample input, desired output, current output and an explanation of the differences.

Comment: @underscore_d , I've posted the answer below!

Answer (score -1):

This finally worked! if you think this is not the best solution, post your alternative please.

```
bool charVerify(string word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    {
        int character = toupper(word[i]);
        if(character == ' ' || character == '.')
        {
                character='A';
        }
        if (character < 'A' || character > 'Z')
        {
            return false;

        }

    }
    return true;
}

void setFname()
{

    string fname;
    cout << "Enter Name: ";
    getline(std::cin.ignore(),fname);
    while(1)
    {
        if (charVerify(fname))
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\tInvalid Input! Only [a-z,A-Z,SPACE,PERIOD]" << endl;

        }
        cin.clear();
        cout << "Enter Name: ";
        getline(std::cin.ignore(),fname);
    }
    firstname = fname;
}
```